# Disable highlight of an external event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I am using the fullcalendar jquery plugin v2.6.1. Actually, I want to prevent the highlighted option of an external events while dragging to the calendar.

Is there any possible way to disable the `fc-highlight` from the event or any option to show the highlight on the basis of event size. I mean to say that I have an external event with start and end time e.g the event starts from 10:00 and ends at 11:00 but when I'm dragging that event to the calendar, the `fc-highlight` always covered the two hours slot.

Picture attached below

[image]

So in the picture, the grayish highlighted box in red stroke **Event 2** which is only available for one hour slot but the highlighted background covers two hours which I want to disable it or just make it one hour. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the solution by adding `defaultTimedEventDuration: 01:00:00` in FullCalendar options or adding `duration` in an external events, something like this:

```
<div class="external fc-event" duration="04:00">Event</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but if you will set **end time** in drop function for the external event then you don't need to disable the highlight. Try this:

```
var eventsArray = [];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    drop: function(date) {

        var eventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        var eventObjectDuplicate = $.extend({}, eventObject);

        eventObjectDuplicate.start  = date;
        eventObjectDuplicate.end    = (date.getTime() + 1800000)/1000;
        eventObjectDuplicate.allDay = false;

        eventsArray.push(eventObjectDuplicate);

    }

)};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @miqureshi but actually, I already have the start and end time of an event and I know how to remove the **fc-highlight** from the core fullcalendar.js file, but that's not the correct way so looking for proper way of disabling or setting the end time for **fc-highlight** as well.